What is the point of using AWS SecretsManager?
My question sounds silly, and it probably is, but I set up and used AWS SecretsManager for the first time and actually, after doing it, I have a hard time in seeing the point of using it.
I'm saying to myself that I'm probably using it wrong, so I'd like to have a couple of use cases where it is indeed useful.
I'm pretty used to secrets managements and whatnot; I run a web application where I keep all the secrets as hidden env. vars. and both my web server and my deployment pipelines access them as hidden variables.
Now I had to launch an EC2 for one of my guys to do some ML stuff on. It has to be able to connect to my DB, so I set up the connection for him as a utility function that returns the connection already set up; problem is, I need the DB credentials to do it. Since I don't want them to be exposed, I saved them in AWS SecretsManager, granted access to SecretsManager to my EC2, and modified the utility function to read them before opening a DB connection.
Everything works great, but I wonder: why is it in any way better than having for example a .env file to read from? I mean, the credentials are now not hardcoded, and this is fine; but whoever gets access to the machine can print the values I get from the SecretsManager, and this makes the whole point useless to me.
So my question is: what are some useful cases for using SecretsManager?

How do you populate the .env file?  Manually copying it over?  That might work for small setups.  If you want to populate them automatically, you have a last mile problem.  What stores the secrets so they can be automatically retrieved?   Somewhere safe?  Where do you put those credentials?   Putting them in an AWS service accessible by an ec2 instance via role credentials solves this last mile problem.  Why secrets manager in particular?  Maybe because it integrates easier into other services; maybe just because AWS forgot to monetize Parameter Store.

Thank you, your comment + the answer below make a complete answer to me! You should add it to the answer itself :)

Think of Secrets Manager (or Systems Manager Parameter Store) as "Environment variables in the cloud".

Secret Manager is just another way of storing secrets with add-ons like automated credentials rotation, auditing support to see who has accessed what, central management in case you are using same secret across multiple services.
Bad bots are always looking to extract .env files. So unless your server is private or you have good measures in place like a firewall I'd recommend using secret manager based on above benefits in production systems.
